# How to truncate a string to a specific length in perl?

Tags: perl

I am just unable to find "truncate a string to a specific length" in Perl.
Is there any built in way?

**UPDATE:**

input:  `$str = "abcd";`

output (truncate for 3 characters): $str is `abc`

Comment: Can you provide a sample INPUT/OUTPUT for better clarity ?

Comment: Not worth making a dedicated answer for this, but...if you're truncating a `printf` statement with a hexadecimal representation of an integer, using bitshift works better than `substr`: `printf "%x %x", time*1000 >> 12, time`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You want to use the `substr()` function.

```
$shortened = substr( $long, 0, 50 ); # 50 characters long, starting at the beginning.
```

For more, use `perldoc`

```
perldoc -f substr
```

In your case, it would be:

```
$str = 'abcd';
$short = substr( $str, 0, 3 );
```

Comment: I'd advise a little caution with this answer as it may slice wide (Unicode) characters in half. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649259/substr-in-perl-cutting-utf8-characters-in-half

Answer (score 10):

For a string of arbitrary length, where truncate length can be longer than string length, I would opt for a substitution

```
$str =~ s/.{3}\K.*//s;
```

For shorter strings, the substitution will not match and the string will be unchanged. The convenient `\K` escape can be replaced with a lookbehind assertion, or a simple capture:

```
s/(?<=.{3}).*//s   # lookbehind
s/(.{3}).*/$1/s    # capture
```

Comment: Note for those interested: in perl v5.20 (at least), the length of  lookbehind assertion is limited to 255.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably useful to also mention that, instead of `substr()` or regular expressions, you could use `printf` or `sprintf`.

See  [`perldoc -f sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) :

> For string conversions, specifying a precision truncates the string to
>   fit the specified width:
>
> ```
>   printf '<%.5s>', "truncated";   # prints "<trunc>"
>   printf '<%10.5s>', "truncated"; # prints "<     trunc>"
> ```

Answer (score 4):

As long as your original string is at least 3 characters long, you can use a call to `substr` as an lvalue.

```
my $str = "abcd";
substr($str, 3) = "";
print "$str\n";   # prints "abc"
```

The initial length of the string may need to be checked, as if it is shorter than 3 characters, the return value of this call to `substr` cannot be assigned to (see `perldoc -f substr` for more information) and attempting to do so will cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to do like `php` `wordwrap()` a string, so :

```
use Text::Format;
print Text::Format->new({columns => 50})->format($string);
```

If you just need the first N characters :

```
print substr $string, 0, 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use regexp to do the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $str = "abcd";

$str =~ /(\w{0,3})/;
print $1;
```

Comment: This does not modify $str, only places the match in $1 - other answers might be easier to use in a practical manner.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way is to use substr to extract the part you want:

```
$first_n = substr($string, 0, $n);
```

If you only want to modify the string and you are certain it is at least the desired length:

```
substr($string, $n) = '';
```

If you are not certain, you can do:

```
use List::Util "min";
substr($string, min($n, length($string))) = '';
```

or catch the exception:

```
eval { substr($string, $n) = '' };
```