# Substr in Perl, cutting utf8 characters in half

Tags: perl, substr

I'm trying to figure out a problem when using `substr` in Perl v5.8.5. Here is an example string:

> טוב בגןUTF-8 Examples עץ טוב בגן いろはにほξεσκεπάζω ff

```
if (length($hit->{post_title}) > 60) {
  $hit->{post_title} = substr($hit->{post_title},0,60);
  $hit->{post_title} .= "...";
}
```

Seems to get trimmed to:

> UTF-8 Examples עץ טוב בגן いろはにほξεσκε�...

In the code, I see a message about a wide character. I'm wondering if maybe `substr` is somehow cutting the word in half? If I remove the `substr()` part of the code, then the string shows up fine.

I've never come across this with utf8 before. Do we need to do something special with arabic characters?

UPDATE: If I check for the length of the strings before and after, something funky does seem to be going on:

> TEST: UTF-8 Examples עץ טוב בגן いろはにほξεσκεπάζω
>   LENGTH: 63
>   LENGTH: 67 AFTER

I'm just not sure what! FWIW, I'm also using this in the header of the script:

```
use utf8;
```

Thanks!

Comment: May be try this `use open ':encoding(utf8)'; binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';`

Comment: @ssr1012 - thanks, but that seems to make it worse (breaks the encoding: `UTF-8 Examples ×¢×¥ ××× ××× ããã¯ã«ã»Î¾ÎµÏÎºÎµÏ` )

Comment: Where does your string come from? If it's being read from a file, you'll want to decode the data into Perl characters as you read the file. If it's part of your source code, you'll want to add `use utf8` to your program so Perl knows it's UTF-8. In both cases, you'll want to encode the characters into UTF-8 before you print them and tell the output filehandle to expect UTF-8 data. See (perlunitut)[http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html] for details.

Comment: Also, it would be good if you could supply us with a complete runnable example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @DaveCross thanks. I managed to find a work around using `Unicode::String`. The problem with this script, is that its HORRIBLE (its a very old BBS type system). I'm not sure what the guy was smoking when he wrote it, but the architecture is awful. Anyway, it lives to die another day :)

Answer (score 3):

Typically, I've now found a work-around. Its not super pretty, but it seems to work

```
use Unicode::String qw(utf8);

$us = utf8($hit->{post_title});
if ($us->length > 30) {
    $hit->{post_title} = $us->substr(0,30);
}
```

So basically stick the utf8 string into Unicode::String, and then if it's over a given size, trim it down and pass back into `$hit->{post_title}`. It's not pretty, but does the job.

Unfortunately this is an archaic (2000's!) bit of software, and the owner (a charity) doesn't want to do the upgrade to a better forum software. I've been trying to convince him for a while, but its a no-go. It's going to get to a point where I can't keep "updating" it for him, as the code was such a mess even out of the box. Anyway, this seems to be one battle won for now :)

Comment: I suspect that's just a thin wrapper around the suggestions that we made in the comments on your question.

Comment: @DaveCross - yeah probably. Seeing as I'm doing this for free for him, I don't really want to spend hours and hours debugging it. I've already spent a couple of hours on it, and there are still other places to "fix" it up. I've explained that he really need to look at something a bit newer than 2000, to bring it up to date (he thinks it's more secure on older software, but I beg to differ!)

Comment: That is not a workaround. That's how you do it. Perl has two types of strings: ASCII and UTF-8. In the OP's code, the string has UTF-8 characters in an ASCII string. The correct solution is to convert it to an UTF-8 string. And that's how you do it.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: Perl doesn't have ASCII strings and UTF-8 strings. It has binary strings (that assume all characters are a single byte) and text strings (that don't make that assumption). If you're lucky enough to be dealing with data where all characters are single bytes, then you probably have IS0-8859-1 (aka "Latin-1"), not ASCII. And there are plenty of ways to convert between the two types of string. Unicode::String is one of the more obscure.

Comment: @DaveCross If you want to call it binary, that's fine but the encoding may be anything so assuming it's ASCII means you would make as fewer mistakes. And there is a flag on all string that indicates it is UTF-8. If the flag is off, it's a binary string. If it's on, it's UTF-8.

Comment: It's not what I call it, it's what [Perl's documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) calls it.